# pytest get all dynamic command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, command-line-arguments, argparse

How do setup dynamic command line arguments in pytest? So I don't know all the possible arguments the user might run the test with, so I want to get a list/dict of all the arguments the user passes in the command line and use them accordingly(pass them(if any present) onto some functions in my code).

I want to be able to run the following commands, but I don't want to define in the test script that only *arg1*, *arg2*, and *arg3* are accepted.

```
pytest test_abc.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2
pytest test_abc.py --arg3 val3
```

If the above is not possible, is there a way I could have all the possible arguments in a file or something and then use it somehow? Can this be done using pytest.ini file, if yes, how so?

I've seen the following method but I don't want to use it

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--arg1", action="store_true", default="val", help="arg1"
    )
```

If I haven't used `parser.addoption()` method to define `arg1` then I get the following error.

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --arg1 val1
  inifile: None
  rootdir: $ROOT_DIR
```

I basically want a dictionary(key-value pairs) of the all the arguments passed in the command line, but I don't want to pre-define these arguments anywhere in the code.

Comment: you can use `argparse` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I don't want to define all the arguments before-hand

Comment: If you aren't defining it beforehand, what is the rule that tells you what arguments are acceptable, and when exactly is it supposed to figure that out? When you plan to "pass them on to some functions in the code", how do you intend to figure out which should be passed to what function?

Comment: `pytest` is using `argparse` (or optionally `optparse`).  So even if has provided a way of defining arguments for your script, it can't handler arbitrary `key/value` pairs.  Typically for `argparse` we recommend accepting strings like `arg1=value` (quoted if necessary), and parsing them yourself.

Comment: Looks like `pytest` has extended `argparse` for its own purposes.  https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/_modules/_pytest/config/argparsing.html.  I'd have to study it (or the docs) to see what added capabilities it has added.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just want all arguments to be accepted. If I've them as key-value pairs, I can figure it out.

Comment: @hpaulj, I'll look into that. If not arbitrary `key/value` pairs, can it accept arbitrary strings like `arg1=value` and then I could parse that?

Comment: The question is rather what are you trying to achieve. Are you writing a test for a command line utility?